# Either backup only values or convert formulas to values after backup

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, I'm trying to backup a google spreadsheet via apps script, because each month the data is going to change, and I want a record of what the data was in the past. 
I can make a copy of the spreadsheet just fine.

```
function makeCopy() {

// generates the timestamp and stores in variable formattedDate as year-month-date hour-minute-second
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");

// gets the name of the original file and appends the word "copy" followed by the timestamp stored in formattedDate
var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + formattedDate;

// gets the destination folder by their ID. REPLACE xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx with your folder's ID that you can get by opening the folder in Google Drive and checking the URL in the browser's address bar
var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("I know this is supposed to be the folderID");

// gets the current Google Sheet file
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId())

// makes copy of "file" with "name" at the "destination"
file.makeCopy(name, destination);


}
```

But, the data in the spreadsheet will change based on the formulas within a day or so after I'm done for the month. I only want to copy the values. I've been scratching my head about this for a few hours now, and was wondering if anyone had any thoughts? I'm not particularly good at coding, so, it'll have to be decently basic responses.

One thought I had was to make copies of all the sheets in the spreadsheet, convert those into values, copy those sheets to a new spreadsheet maybe, then delete those copies in the original? It would be a bit tedious, but there's only 4 tabs right now. "Form" "BankRecords" "Transactions" and "GLAccounts"

Answer (score 1):

- For the copied Spreadsheet, you want to convert the values given by the formulas to only values without the formulas.
- You want to achieve this by modifying your Google Apps Script.

#### Modification point:

- In this case, I would like to propose to convert above situation using `copyTo` to the copied Spreadsheet.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified as the simple modification, please modify as follows.

From:

```
file.makeCopy(name, destination);
```

To:

```
const copiedSpreadsheet = file.makeCopy(name, destination);
SpreadsheetApp.open(copiedSpreadsheet).getSheets().forEach(r => {
  const range = r.getDataRange();
  range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});
});
```

#### Note:

- Please enable V8 at the script editor.

#### Reference:

- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)

Comment: It's close, it seems to make a copy with only values, however I have some importranges that are showing as #REF instead of the values it was showing :\

Comment: @Chris McMahon Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to think of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, I made an ugly workaround. If anyone wants to tell me how to clean it up, that'd be great, but if not, it's at least functional. My fix: 
I made an intermediary backup sheet, that was given all permissions to do importranges for each of the sheets required.
Then I made a function based off this: https://www.labnol.org/code/20239-copy-google-spreadsheets
for each tab I wanted backed up. (Lots of duplication, unfortunately, and If I ever want to add a bunch more tabs, it'll be a pain in the neck.)
Then after all of those functions, I added back in the original makecopy function, tweaked so that it would copy based on the intermediary backup instead.
Here's the code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Scripts')
      .addItem('Backup', 'cloneGoogleSheet')
      .addToUi();
}

function cloneGoogleSheet() {
cloneMain()
cloneCR()
cloneGS()
cloneJD()
cloneJS()
cloneJW()
cloneKS()
cloneSS()
cloneTR()
cloneWJ()
cloneWK()
makeCopy()
}

function cloneMain(Main, Main1) {

  // source doc
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1VM1Pf4PQyP2V_oNDcTHADdqQ-9hY8vALHuEnuIhOKG4');

  // source sheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Main');

  // Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();

  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();

  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  // target spreadsheet
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1NP7GNjnGHpkRcm7nG_-_Of8f--zQiG7GxO_aOY3ppXE');

  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Main1');

  // Clear the Google Sheet before copy
  ts.clear({contentsOnly: true});

  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

};

function cloneCR(CR, CR1) {

  // source doc
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1VM1Pf4PQyP2V_oNDcTHADdqQ-9hY8vALHuEnuIhOKG4');

  // source sheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('CR');

  // Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();

  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();

  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  // target spreadsheet
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1NP7GNjnGHpkRcm7nG_-_Of8f--zQiG7GxO_aOY3ppXE');

  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('CR1');

  // Clear the Google Sheet before copy
  ts.clear({contentsOnly: true});

  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

};

function cloneGS(GS, GS1) {

  // source doc
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1VM1Pf4PQyP2V_oNDcTHADdqQ-9hY8vALHuEnuIhOKG4');

  // source sheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('GS');

  // Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();

  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();

  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  // target spreadsheet
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1NP7GNjnGHpkRcm7nG_-_Of8f--zQiG7GxO_aOY3ppXE');

  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('GS1');

  // Clear the Google Sheet before copy
  ts.clear({contentsOnly: true});

  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

};

function cloneJD(JD, JD1) {

  // source doc
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1VM1Pf4PQyP2V_oNDcTHADdqQ-9hY8vALHuEnuIhOKG4');

  // source sheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('JD');

  // Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();

  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();

  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  // target spreadsheet
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1NP7GNjnGHpkRcm7nG_-_Of8f--zQiG7GxO_aOY3ppXE');

  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('JD1');

  // Clear the Google Sheet before copy
  ts.clear({contentsOnly: true});

  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

};

function cloneJS(JS, JS1) {

  // source doc
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1VM1Pf4PQyP2V_oNDcTHADdqQ-9hY8vALHuEnuIhOKG4');

  // source sheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('JS');

  // Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();

  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();

  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  // target spreadsheet
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1NP7GNjnGHpkRcm7nG_-_Of8f--zQiG7GxO_aOY3ppXE');

  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('JS1');

  // Clear the Google Sheet before copy
  ts.clear({contentsOnly: true});

  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

};

function cloneJW(JW, JW1) {

  // source doc
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1VM1Pf4PQyP2V_oNDcTHADdqQ-9hY8vALHuEnuIhOKG4');

  // source sheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('JW');

  // Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();

  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();

  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  // target spreadsheet
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1NP7GNjnGHpkRcm7nG_-_Of8f--zQiG7GxO_aOY3ppXE');

  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('JW1');

  // Clear the Google Sheet before copy
  ts.clear({contentsOnly: true});

  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

};

function cloneKS(KS, KS1) {

  // source doc
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1VM1Pf4PQyP2V_oNDcTHADdqQ-9hY8vALHuEnuIhOKG4');

  // source sheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('KS');

  // Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();

  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();

  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  // target spreadsheet
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1NP7GNjnGHpkRcm7nG_-_Of8f--zQiG7GxO_aOY3ppXE');

  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('KS1');

  // Clear the Google Sheet before copy
  ts.clear({contentsOnly: true});

  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

};

function cloneSS(SS, SS1) {

  // source doc
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1VM1Pf4PQyP2V_oNDcTHADdqQ-9hY8vALHuEnuIhOKG4');

  // source sheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('SS');

  // Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();

  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();

  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  // target spreadsheet
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1NP7GNjnGHpkRcm7nG_-_Of8f--zQiG7GxO_aOY3ppXE');

  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('SS1');

  // Clear the Google Sheet before copy
  ts.clear({contentsOnly: true});

  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

};

function cloneTR(TR, TR1) {

  // source doc
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1VM1Pf4PQyP2V_oNDcTHADdqQ-9hY8vALHuEnuIhOKG4');

  // source sheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('TR');

  // Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();

  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();

  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  // target spreadsheet
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1NP7GNjnGHpkRcm7nG_-_Of8f--zQiG7GxO_aOY3ppXE');

  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('TR1');

  // Clear the Google Sheet before copy
  ts.clear({contentsOnly: true});

  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

};

function cloneWJ(WJ, WJ1) {

  // source doc
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1VM1Pf4PQyP2V_oNDcTHADdqQ-9hY8vALHuEnuIhOKG4');

  // source sheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('WJ');

  // Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();

  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();

  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  // target spreadsheet
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1NP7GNjnGHpkRcm7nG_-_Of8f--zQiG7GxO_aOY3ppXE');

  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('WJ1');

  // Clear the Google Sheet before copy
  ts.clear({contentsOnly: true});

  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

};

function cloneWK(WK, WK1) {

  // source doc
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1VM1Pf4PQyP2V_oNDcTHADdqQ-9hY8vALHuEnuIhOKG4');

  // source sheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('WK');

  // Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();

  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();

  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  // target spreadsheet
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1NP7GNjnGHpkRcm7nG_-_Of8f--zQiG7GxO_aOY3ppXE');

  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('WK1');

  // Clear the Google Sheet before copy
  ts.clear({contentsOnly: true});

  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

};

function makeCopy() {

// generates the timestamp and stores in variable formattedDate as year-month-date hour-minute-second
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST5EDT", "yyyyMMdd' 'HH:mm");

// gets the name of the original file and appends the word "copy" followed by the timestamp stored in formattedDate
var name = "Master Sheet - " + formattedDate;

// gets the destination folder by their ID. REPLACE xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx with your folder's ID that you can get by opening the folder in Google Drive and checking the URL in the browser's address bar
var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1E5EodsDaaT6a8wkRZ-NtmszzV9DTgQok");

// gets the intermediary backup
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1NP7GNjnGHpkRcm7nG_-_Of8f--zQiG7GxO_aOY3ppXE')

// makes copy of "file" with "name" at the "destination"
file.makeCopy(name, destination);



}
```